# How can I get unique names from the column

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I have to fetch only the unique names from the city:

```
table: cities

+----+--------+
| id |  name  |
+----+--------+
|  1 |  Rawal |
+----+--------+
|  2 |  Nina  |
+----+--------+
|  3 |  Monte |
+----+--------+
|  4 |  Nina  |
+----+--------+
|  5 | Samina |
+----+--------+
```

I only need to get unique names, in e.g. Rawal, Monte and Samina.

```
SELECT DISTINCT name FROM cities
```

also gives `Nina` which I don't need.

Comment: are you sure the name is the same  and don't contain  hidden chars???

Comment: A simple join will suffice

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want names that appear once.  Think `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`:

```
select name
from cities
group by name
having count(*) = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT DISTINCT TRIM(name) FROM cities;`

Answer (score 0):

Use `TRIM` to delete spaces on both sides of the data in column and then use `UPPER` to ensure that the data is `DISTINCT` case-insensitively.

`NOTE`: you can use `LOWER` also instead of `UPPER` to compare case-insensitively

```
SELECT DISTINCT UPPER(TRIM(name)) FROM cities;
```